# Doing an upsert in oracle SQL based on 2 fields

Tags: sql, oracle, upsert

I've the following SQL statement for an oracle DB (actually a list of statements like that).

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_DATA (username, data_id, version) 
SELECT username, 12345, '1.0' 
FROM SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_USER;
```

In the DB some combination of the username and ID are already imported. 
I would like to run these statements with upsert so that all not missing entries are inserted (username, id, version) all others get updated (version).

Is there a way without using PLSQL (begin - exception ...)

Comment: use insert where ```not exists```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways:

Using `NOT EXISTS`

```
INSERT INTO SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_DATA (username, data_id, version) 
SELECT username, 12345, '1.0' 
FROM SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_USER A
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
FROM SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_DATA NE
WHERE NE.username = A.username
And ne.data_id = 12345);
```

Using `merge`: -- updated

```
MERGE INTO SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_DATA T
USING (SELECT username, 12345 data_id, '1.0' version
FROM SCHEMA_ABC.TBL_USER) D
ON (T.USERNAME = D.USERNAME 
AND T.DATA_ID = D.DATA_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET VERSION = VERSION + 1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT(username, data_id, version) 
Values
(D.USERNAME, D.DATA_ID, D.VERSION);
```

Cheers!!

Comment: This is not working - as it is only a insert if not exists - but there is no update if the version changes.